# Python BeautifulSoup html parser not working

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Here i'm trying to read the page and create a csv with columns respectively. But i'm unable to read the parsed data to use find function. The soup data doesn't have the data present in webpage

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.fancraze.com/marketplace/sales/mornemorkel1?tab=latest-sales"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 0):

Site use API to get data, so you can handle it

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://api.faze.app/v1/latestSalesInAGroup/mornemorkel1'
result = []
response = requests.get(url=url)
for data in response.json()['data']:
    data = {
        'id': data['momentId']['id'],
        'seller': data['sellerAddress']['userName'],
        'buyer': data['buyerAddress']['userName'],
        'price': data['price'],
        'created': data['createdAt']
    }
    result.append(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(df)
```

OUTPUT:

```
      id                     seller  ... price                   created
0   1882                   singal22  ...     8  2022-06-22T14:34:39.403Z
1   1737           olive_creepy2343  ...     7  2022-06-22T14:09:32.070Z
2   1256          tomato_wicked3294  ...    10  2022-06-22T13:49:20.895Z
3   1931  aquamarine_productive9244  ...     6  2022-06-22T13:41:49.153Z
4   1603  aquamarine_productive9244  ...     9  2022-06-22T13:28:01.624Z
..   ...                        ...  ...   ...                       ...
95  1026           olive_creepy2343  ...     7  2022-04-16T18:00:00.662Z
96  1719                 Hhassan136  ...     5  2022-04-14T23:14:12.037Z
97  2054                 Cricket101  ...     5  2022-04-14T21:30:13.185Z
98  1961                  emzeden_9  ...     6  2022-04-14T18:02:05.194Z
99  1194       amaranth_curious1871  ...     5  2022-04-14T17:45:25.266Z
```